# I wish to say "you can do it" but how I wish to is clearly wrong

Tags: grammar, english-to-german, verb, vocabulary, compound

Ich wünsche schreiben "Du schaffst es schön"

Vorher mein Autokorrektur macht "Schafts" genau sowie, mit "s" als Groß. Wir alle wissen, keinen Verben sind sowie, deswegen habe ich gefragt.

Aber jetzt der Autokorrektur macht zwei "f" wenn ich um eine kontraction machen versuchten. Und alles klar damit, aber ich habe noch eine Frage bitte. Ich habe vergessen, wann schön und schon zu nutzen. Ich glaube da oben ist falsch, oder?

Auch, wenn ich immer noch ein Kontraktion machen würden, würde es sei einfach, "Du schaffst's schon!"?

Comment: Do not use a spelling checker. You are at a stage of learning a language at which it not only won't help, but is actively harmful. Switch it off. Right now. I mean it. Best advice you'll get all month.

Comment: Leider verstehe ich den Kern deiner Frage nicht. Aber "schön" ist in der Tat falsch. "Du schaffst das schon" ist richtig. Du kannst "schon" auch weglassen. "Du schaffst das". Alternative: "Du kannst es schaffen", ist aber etwas weniger motivierend.

Comment: Die Autokorrektur interpretiert *schaffts* bzw. *schafts* als Genetiv des Nomens *der Schaft*, also *des Schafts* oder *des Schaftes*. Falsches Wort (the shaft in eng.). Guter Rat von @RegDwight, die Autokorrektur auszuschalten.

Answer (score 3):

> **schön** - beautiful, lovely
>
> **schon** - already, yet, before

"Du schaffst das schon" / "Du schaffst es schon" - Are both valid in this case.

*"Du schaffst's schon"* - It shouldn't be used in formal written conversations and its only rarely used in informal spoken conversations (as pointed out by guidot).

Comment: Second variant is also encountered and valid in my opinion, at least  in informal conversation; i would not write it, though.

Comment: Yeah, in an informal, spoken conversation the second option could be possible(if not very likely), even if I've never encountered it.

Comment: „Du schaffst’s schon” sounds REALLY unfamiliar to me. Northern Germany speaking ;)
Even when used in colloquial language, I’d rather say it like „Du schaffstas schon“ (written like heard, not grammatically correct).

Comment: I think the point is that "das" is not fully pronounced. Another example: "Das's so" for "Das ist so". There is a slight "e" or "ä" sound ("Dases so"). And similar is it with "schaffst's", also with a slight "e" or "ä" sound. I know the variation with "a", too, but that's dropping the "d" sound only.

Comment: The "schaffst's" is unpronounceable, at least for the majority of German speakers (and yes, even more in the Northern areas). "Das schaffste schon." is another regional shortening/fusion of syllables. But keep in mind about slang and regional expressions for beginners: You must *understand* them, but should *not use* them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm from Berlin and we would vary the saying into

> "(Das) Schaffst du schon."

"Das" can be left out. That makes it sound a little more colloquial than "Du schaffst es schon", maybe that is what you wanted to achieve with the "schaffst's" contraction.

And I completely support the notion that you should switch off the spelling checker, because they very, very often suggest a different word than the one you have in mind - you must know what you want to write! I don't want to put you off, I know German is hard to learn - but to be honest - I just understood your question through guessing and imagination. Please do not use the spelling checker at this stage of your language learning, you'll only make it harder for yourself. You'll gain better understanding out of reading and writing exercises.

However, your spelling checker has a dictionary behind it, so it meant well ;) Just in case you wondered: what it was trying to suggest was the Genitive of *engl. shaft*

> der Schaft (m.)
>
> - (Gen.) des Schaftes, des Schafts